# Kernel patch 4.15.0-72 for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS not available on canonical-livepatch

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, canonical-livepatch

I there seems to be the situation about the new kernel security upgrade on Ubuntu that is announced over the mailing list and available via dist-upgrade, but there doesn't seem to be a live patch from Canonical. The command **canonical-livepatch status** seems to give the **patchState: nothing-to-apply** result. See here:

```
root@efk:~# canonical-livepatch status
client-version: 9.4.6
architecture: x86_64
cpu-model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-4850 v3 @ 2.20GHz
last-check: 2019-12-03T09:43:33+01:00
boot-time: 2019-11-14T08:26:02+01:00
uptime: 458h17m19s
status:
- kernel: 4.15.0-70.79-generic
  running: true
  livepatch:
    checkState: checked
    patchState: nothing-to-apply
    version: ""
    fixes: ""

root@efk:~#
```

and here:

```
root@efk:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:3 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Fetched 88.7 kB in 1s (152 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
root@efk:~# apt-get -s dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-72 linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-72-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic
The following packages have been kept back:
  xe-guest-utilities
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
3 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Inst linux-modules-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Inst linux-generic [4.15.0.70.72] (4.15.0.72.74 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-image-generic [4.15.0.70.72] (4.15.0.72.74 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-headers-4.15.0-72 (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all]) []
Inst linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64]) []
Inst linux-headers-generic [4.15.0.70.72] (4.15.0.72.74 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-modules-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-image-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-generic (4.15.0.72.74 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-image-generic (4.15.0.72.74 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-headers-4.15.0-72 (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [all])
Conf linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic (4.15.0-72.81 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
Conf linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.72.74 Ubuntu:18.04/bionic-updates [amd64])
root@efk:~#
```

Please any info?

FYI: **competing product KernelCare on a Debian stretch system had performed a live patch.**

gmt42

Comment: canonical-livepatch has some rather strange issues - if a reboot is required or it's not working (i.e. wrong kernel) it still happily tells you it's working on motd at login, you can't really get data out of it... I'm rather disappointed by it - this lack of communication here unfortunatly fit's perfectly into my experience...